# Supress Today link in Django admin date widget

Tags: python, django, datefield

I would like to suppress the today link that is available by default in Django admin for a date field.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution is to subclass the DateField widget used in the admin and tweak the render() method to not show the link.

You can find an example of the general approach to subclassing widgets [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1649/):

And to get that widget to be used in the admin, you can set that in the admin.py for the relevant app. Here's the official documentation on [how to do that](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides)